# Error while installing NodeJS in Windows "Path not specified"

Tags: node.js

I messed up my hard disks and lost some information. I formatted them completely and installed everything back on, but when I install NodeJS it says "The specified path 'D:\Config.Msi\' is unavailable".

[image]